# Script to mail PDF files

Tags: shell, ksh, pdf

It's a wrong question..please delete itn

Answer (score 1):

You get `cpb9998hp1outputPDFOUT.pdf` as attachment file name because you specify it. The `uuencode` man pages clearly specifies the last parameter is the output name. If you don't want that provide the right parameter to `uuencode`:

```
OUTPUT=/cpb/9998/hp1/output/
BASENAME=PDFOUT.pdf
ATTFILE="$OUTPUT$BASENAME"
uuencode "$ATTFILE" "$BASENAME" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$MAILTO"
```

Comment: doing this email is not coming now

Comment: @Pooja You should not be "doing this", because in this e.g. $MAILTO is not defined. What you should be doing take  whatever you did and integrate integrate the relevant parts in that and make sure it is called. I tested this on my side (with for me correct values of MAILTO, SUBJECT, and a different OUTPUT and thinks worked)

Comment: You mean I should be doing like this                                               

 OUTPUT=/cpb/9998/hp1/output/
 date_time=`date +"%m-%d-%Y %T"`
 BASENAME=PDFOUT.pdf
 ATTFILE="$OUTPUT$BASENAME"       # File to be attached and generally requiring encoding
 SUBJECT="AUTOMATE HO GAYA CCA PDF for "$date_time              # Change as needed
 MAILTO=mugdha.garde@sce.com                        # Ditto
 MAILTO=supriya.sahu@sce.com                        # Ditto
 

 uuencode "$ATTFILE" "$BASENAME" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" $MAILTO

Comment: I tried with what you said but still mail is not coming

Comment: Take your original script and **only** change the line starting with `uuencode $ATTFILE $ATTFILE | ` to `uuencode $ATTFILE PDFOUT.pdf | ` leaving the rest of that line the same.

Comment: I tried but still its not working